# how to compare 2 dependent variables

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, independence

What is the correct way to compare correlation between 2 dependent variables in R?

Thanks

Edit:
Here is the edited question and apologize for not asking this correctly before:

I acquired 2 measures from 2 different experiments and I want to know whether these 2 measures are correlated.

The problem is Measure 1 is confounded by some other covariates. So, I went ahead and did multiple regression and found the coefficient of my main effect. Since this is an estimate it has a mean with a deviation.

I could do cor(mean(parameter_estimate, Measure_2)) but I need to know if this correlation is significant. Is this right as I dont incorporate the spread of the estimate (variance)? My guess is the mean may be significant but with the standard error of the estimate, the correlation may become insignificant.

Thank you for your help

Regards

Comment: If they are correlated/dependent you get their correlation with `cor(x,y)`.

However, I'm not entirely sure whether that's the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As @Harald Thomson mentioned, this is easy using the `cor(x,y)` function.  Here is an example in R.

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(20, 10, 5), x2 = rnorm(20, 10, 5))
cor(dat$x1, dat$x2)

>[1] 0.2856422
```

Therefore, a positive correlation exists of 0.29.  This can easily be modified in a larger data.frame.

"Correct" can be interrupted in many different ways under many different assumptions.  A more specific question would help determine what correlation you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Harold and Amstell. Please refer my edited question. Thanks again.